# Concatenar nome tabela loop sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando preencher uma tabela minha com um loop no sql server
segue o código:

```
declare @i int
set @i =1
while @i < 5
begin
INSERT INTO TABELA VALUES('teste')
set @i =  @i + 1
end
```

Gostaria de concatenar ali o nome ta tabela no insert com o número da variável @i

Criando tabela1,tabela2,tabela3 ...etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode executar qualquer query dinâmica no SQL Server usando a rotina [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Exemplo:

```sql
declare @i int
declare @sql nvarchar(500)
set @i =1
while @i <= 5
begin

    set @sql = N'INSERT INTO TABELA' 
      + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @i) 
      + ' VALUES(''teste ' 
      + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @i) + ''')'
    execute sp_executesql @sql
    set @i =  @i + 1

end
```

### [Demo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72256/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @i int
set @i =1
while @i < 5
begin
INSERT INTO TABELA VALUES('tabela' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR))
set @i =  @i + 1
end
```